# What event is for choosing item from combobox, not actionevent?

Tags: javafx

I have editable combobox.

```
 tf_name.getEditor().setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
        tf_name.hide();
        String name= tf_name.getEditor().getText().trim();
        tf_name.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();


        tf_name.getEditor().setText(name);
        tf_name.setItems(Customer.getNameCompanyList(name));
        int size=Customer.getNameCompanyList(name).size();
        if (size>10) {size=10;
            if (size==0) size=0;
        }
        tf_name.setVisibleRowCount(size);
        if (size!=0)
            tf_name.show();
        tf_name.getEditor().end();
        /*tv_info1.setItems(Info2.getInfo2NameDog(name));*/} );
    tf_name.setOnAction(  e->{
        {

            Customer customer=Customer.getCustomer(Customer.find_id_cust_Name(tf_name.getValue()));
            tf_phone.setText(customer.getPhone());
            cb_cust_district.setValue(customer.getDistrict());
            cb_city_type.setValue(customer.getCity_type());
            tf_city_name.setText(customer.getCity_name());
            tf_street.setText(customer.getStreet());
            tf_house.setText(String.valueOf(customer.getHouse()));
            tf_housing.setText(customer.getHousing());
            tf_flat.setText(String.valueOf(customer.getFlat()));
            tf_code.setText(String.valueOf(customer.getCode()));
            tf_oplata_nomer.setText(String.valueOf(customer.getNomer_oplat()));
        }



    });
```

i need to do smth when i choose item from combobox, not when i type in combobox or smth else. So what actionevent do i need, instead setOnAction?

Comment: Try adding a listener to the selection model's `selectedIndexProperty`?

Answer (score 0):

You can add change listener to selectedItemProperty of combobox's selectionModel like below demo code:

```
ObservableList<String> options = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); 
        options.addAll("hello", "hi", "bye", "morning");    
        ComboBox<String> myComboBox = new ComboBox<String>();    
        myComboBox.setItems(options);   
        myComboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener( (Observable, oldValue, newValue) -> 
        System.out.println(newValue)
                );
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for helping. Can you augment your code-only answer with some explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Called just after the `ComboBoxBase` popup/display has been hidden. This mean user clicked on an item or click outside of the view.

```
    combo.addEventHandler(ComboBoxBase.ON_HIDDEN, new EventHandler<Event>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {
            EditingUnitCell.this.commitEdit(combo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
        }
    });
```